# Python open and "permission denied" on file with ugo+rw?

Tags: python, linux, permissions, cron

I have a script on a RHEL 7.x machine written in Python3. In testing this script I created a function which will append to a text file in the same directory.

If I execute the script from the local directory ie - `./pyscript.py` everything works as expected.

But I am trying to execute this from a Bash script a couple directories higher and it doesn't seem to work right. The other functions in the script will execute, but this very last one which appends to a text file will not.

Now, if I run the script as the user which owns it(and the txt file) from my home dir, the script errors out with a permission error. BUT if I run the script with `sudo` it finishes with NO error, However it does NOT write to the text file.

My user has RW privileges on every dir between the bash script and the python script.

Any thoughts on why a `sudo` or local user run doesn't seem to let me write to the text file??

**Edit**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ace/ppod/my_venv/emergingThreats/et_pro_watchlists.py", line 165, in <module>
    with open('etProLog.txt', 'a') as outlog:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'etProLog.txt'
```

Comment: Please show the Bash trace. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: @jww I included the traceback and I'll look at those resource now. Thanks!

Comment: Permisssion are rw-rw-rw and it is owned by my user. Like I said when I execute in the same dir it will work fine. All parent dirs are rwx-rwx-rw

Comment: The issue is that relative paths go from the current working directory, not the directory of the python script. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `open("filename.txt", 'mode')`, it will open that file in the directory from which the script is **executed**, not relative to the current directory of the script. If you want the path to directory where the script exists, import the `os` module and use `open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"filename.txt")`. The permission error is because the file doesn't exist; sudo overrides that but does nothing because the file doesn't exist.

Comment: This did it!!!! Thanks I have been pulling my hair out over this one!!!

Comment: Why does Python report “permission denied” instead of "file not found"? Is this one of those decades old Python bugs that never gets fixed?

Comment: FileNotFoundError does happen, it might be a quirk of RHEL?